# Why is groupBy bottlenecking my pipeline?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow, apache-beam

I have a pipeline written in python apache-beam. It windows 800,000 time stamped data into 2 second windows overlapping every 1 second. My elements may have different keys.

When it does a groupBy, it will take 3 hours to complete. I am deployed in cloud dataflow using 10 workers. There isn't a significant increase processing speed when I increase the amount of workers. Why is this transform bottlenecking my pipeline?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the specific tags on this question, but in order to carry out a "groupby" operation (on a non-indexed field), then whatever does the grouping has to sort the entire data set in one place. Without that operation, you probably have data that is easily parallelized. Is that a word?

Comment: Is there a specific job ID demonstrating the problem? As Kenny Ostrom mentioned, gorupby requires not only sorting the data in one place, but also passing that data between workers so that the worker processing a single key has all of the associated values. How large are the elements (this should show up in the Dataflow UI on each step)?

Comment: Unless the elements are huge, doing a groupby on 800,000 elements per se should be very quick. Most likely something else is bottlenecking the pipeline - are you doing something very expensive per-element or per-key? How many different keys are there? (a single key is processed sequentially, so if there's very few keys, that limits the maximum achievable parallelism no matter how many workers you specify) Indeed, it's hard to tell what's going on without a job ID to look at.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. There are about 10 keys on the set of 800,000. I'm assumed it was the groupby because I removed all my other transforms and just had a pipeline with a read, window, group, and write and it took 2.5 hours. Yesterday, I also ran my pipeline on 4.5 million elements and it took 3 hours. Here is the Job Id for the pipeline that ran on 800,000: 2016-09-21_11_43_28-8038866311789986838 and the one on 4.5 million: 2016-09-22_14_39_26-4389793490344760629

Comment: What are you using as the key? How are the keys being computed? Is it possible that all (or most) of your data is on the same key? All of the elements associated with a key need to be processed in sequence on a single worker.

Comment: Keys are session ids, and it is possible that one session has a lot more data than the others. That would definitely explain the consistent processing time  between the two datasets. To verify, is there a way to tell what each worker is doing and how long a task took?

Comment: You can use regular Java logging and look in worker logs (e.g. measure your DoFn's processing time in processElement() and log it if it's more than a threshold), but unfortunately we do not yet provide higher-level tools for debugging "hot key" issues. I looked at these pipelines, and indeed, both of them are effectively bottlenecked by a single very large key. I also recommend turning on autoscaling so that the service can, at least, shut down unused workers so that you do not incur charges for them.

Comment: GroupByKey is a memory bound operation, its not the number of workers you throw at it but the amount of RAM you give it. Try to use less workers but with more RAM each.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the answer from jkff and others:

The pipelines appear to be bottlenecked by a single very large key.  You can use regular Java logging and look in worker logs (e.g. measure your DoFn's processing time in processElement() and log it if it's more than a threshold), but unfortunately we do not yet provide higher-level tools for debugging "hot key" issues.

You can also turn on [autoscaling](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc#autoscaling) so that the service can, at least, shut down unused workers so that you do not incur charges for them.

Comment: Sorry for asking it on an old question, couldn't find a better place. Doesn't a pair of Window+GroupByKey transforms use the "Window+Key" as the key for the group by operation? For example, if the input collection has 800k time series elements, one element per second, and it is windowed into, say 1 minute windows, and then grouped by 10 keys - does it generate 10 groups and then also splits those to fire separate windows, or does it group into 800'000/60 / 10 ~= 1300 groups at once? Beause the comments above (about one big key) lead to think to a former, but this would be a surprising behavior